# Find out total months from tenure which contains both years and month as string in python

Tags: python

I have a list which contains tenure let me show you  -

```
['5 mos', '1 yr 8 mos', '9 mos', '11 mos', '1 yr 1 mo']
```

Basically these are the all over tenure and thrown it into a lists
what I need is basically from that lists is - 58, so total tenure is 58 in months

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does the list always only ever contain strings of the form 'yr', 'mos' and 'mo'?

Comment: Sir I am still trying, it might be a complex way to solve, i have created two empty list, i.e yr = [] and mo = [], now iterating over every item of main list, and then will check if 'yr' is present with any digit then append only that didgit in yr else append in mo.

Comment: For now i have received 'yr', 'mos', and 'mo' so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified by assuming that 'year' starts with 'y' and anything else must indicate months. Therefore:

```
list_ = ['5 mos', '1 yr 8 mos', '9 mos', '11 mos', '1 yr 1 mo']

months = 0

for s in list_:
    t = s.split()
    for a, b in zip(t[::2], t[1::2]):
        n = int(a)
        if b.startswith('y'):
            n *= 12
        months += n

print(months)
```

**Output:**

```
58
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir @Lancelot du Lac, hats off to the logic, :)

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
import re 

l = ['5 mos', '1 yr 8 mos', '9 mos', '11 mos', '1 yr 1 mo']
total = 0
for i in l:
    m = re.search(r'(\d+)\s?mo(?:s)?', i) ## find digits before mo/mos
    m = m.group(1) if m else 0            ## m=0 if no matches
    y = re.search(r'(\d+)\s?yr(?:s)?', i) ## find digits before yr/yrs
    y = y.group(1) if y else 0            ## y=0 if no matches
    total += (int(m)+12*int(y))
print(total)
```

Result:

```
58
```

Comment: Thanks @ytung-dev, this one is also helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can try and parse your list and addup your total months on specific keywords such as mos and yr.

Break down each item of your list into a list containing key words and values.
Assuming the initial list is well formated :

```py
list_ = ['5 mos', '1 yr 8 mos', '9 mos', '11 mos', '1 yr 1 mos']
total = 0
for item in list_:
    string = item.split(' ')
    for i in range (len(string)):
        if string[i] == 'mos':
            total += int(string[i-1])
        if string[i] == 'yr':
            total += 12*int(string[i-1])

print(total)
# 58
```